# ASP Select List

Tags: select, asp-classic

ASP is not my forte, so I was wondering if anyone knows how I can do the following:

I would like when an option within a select drop down list is selected it changes the data within a hidden field.

Here is the test select fields:

```
<select name="h_id">
    <option value="">-- Send enquiry to --</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

So for example if you select option #2 I want it to change the value of the following hidden field:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="testing" value="testing1">
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That would be done on the client-side using javascript.
A very basic example is this:

```
<form>
 <select name="h_id" onChange="setValue(this.value, this.form.testing)">
  <option value="">-- Send enquiry to --</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
 </select>
 <input type="hidden" name="testing" value="testing1">
</form>

​<script>
function setValue(val, target){
    target.value = val;
}
</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have decided to take a different approach, as explained below, any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript and DOM also. Just paste this code and see what values are being assigned

```
<select name="h_id" onchange="fnc(this.value)">
<option value="" >-- Send enquiry to --</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="testing" value="testing1">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function fnc(val)
{
document.getElementsByName("testing").value=val;
alert(document.getElementsByName("testing").value);//this line is just 4 test
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  I have decided to go with a different approach for this, I am looking at having a simple form of name, email, telephone, message and a dropdown (select) and within the form processing script I want to select if an option has been selected to redirect depending on what option has been selected. I am starting this from scratch, so any ideas how I can do this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @craigclicky start using jQuery.. I don't know any particular good tutorial, but a Google for jQuery Form Tutorial gives several ones that are all very usable